# Learning javascript arrays

Tags: javascript

so here is some code and I have basic logic of what's happening but I want to understand what it is doing exactly line by line. I can't find a Javascript code check similar to Python tutor so please help me. I want to understand how LinkedLists work and what this code is doing step by step.
when would we use this in practical examples? what is the difference between this an an array?

Comment: A more specific question would likely be answered better.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how linked lists work? I will say that linked lists are a data structure which means they functionally don't change between languages.

Comment: First of all... Why do you need a linked list instead of a regular array?

Comment: fixed my post. I just want to understand from top to bottom how this code works and what is doing line by line.

Comment: Why did you remove the JS code you wanted explained? Why did you suggest to edit my answer to remove your (explained) code from it? Why does your question's title refer to arrays when your question is about LinkedLists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The basics:**

A linked list is a data structure made of nodes. Each node keeps some useful data and a reference to the next node. To keep a reference to the list you simply keep a reference to the first node. The list ends with a node that has a reference to null instead of another node.

**The JS code (commented):**

```
// node structure:
//{ data: value, // useful data
// next: nextNode } // reference to next node. null for last node


var LinkedList = function() { // constructor function
     this.head = null; // reference to the first node
};

LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(value) { // function you use to insert a new node
     if(this.head === null) { // code for when the list has no nodes.
         this.head = {data: value, next: null}; // simply init the reference to the first node to a node
     } else { // if there are nodes, you need to go through the list to get the to the last node
         var temp = this.head; // start from the first node
         while(temp.next !== null) { // until you find the node that has no next
             temp = temp.next; // go from one node to the next
         }
         temp.next = {data: value, next: null}; // the last node should point to a new node you create (which points to nothing, so it becomes the last node)
     } };
```

**A better solution:**

Keep a pointer to the last node as well in the list structure. Insertion becomes O(1). Deletion is still O(n), it needs to update the pointer if the last node is deleted.

**EDIT: Answer for your new questions**

Generally arrays are better, but there are some cases where a linked list is preferable. One obvious example is in an environment with a lot of fragmented memory. Arrays need a contiguous allocated memory, so if the memory is fragmented, the largest array you can allocate is pretty small. Linked lists can always get more memory anywhere as long as there is space for one more node.
I haven't come across a situation where linked lists were useful in JS (maybe interview questions?), but it's interesting to know that it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like firebug or chrome dev tools, set breakpoint and going in code step by step

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about testing in javascript. You may want to look in to [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) or [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com). I am not familiar with python tutor so I don't know if these are similar but it is a start.